# Apache spark SQL group data by range

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

- I have a table contain a column "age". I want to group people in terms of their age into groups, E.X: [0, 5), [5, 10), [10, 15), ....
- then I will do the same calculations for each group and compare the results.
- The goal of this is to see if the age is related to other variable or not.
- Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Demo:

Sample DF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Bucketizer

scala> val df = spark.range(20).withColumn("age", round(rand()*90).cast(IntegerType))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, age: int]

scala> df.show
+---+---+
| id|age|
+---+---+
|  0| 58|
|  1| 57|
|  2| 43|
|  3| 62|
|  4| 18|
|  5| 70|
|  6| 26|
|  7| 54|
|  8| 70|
|  9| 42|
| 10| 38|
| 11| 79|
| 12| 77|
| 13| 14|
| 14| 87|
| 15| 28|
| 16| 15|
| 17| 59|
| 18| 81|
| 19| 25|
+---+---+
```

Solution:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val splits = Range.Double(0,120,5).toArray

val bucketizer = new Bucketizer()
      .setInputCol("age")
      .setOutputCol("age_range_id")
      .setSplits(splits)

val df2 = bucketizer.transform(df)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

splits: Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0, 35.0, 40.0, 45.0, 50.0, 55.0, 60.0, 65.0, 70.0, 75.0, 80.0, 85.0, 90.0, 95.0, 100.0, 105.0, 110.0, 115.0)
bucketizer: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Bucketizer = bucketizer_3c2040bf50c7
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, age: int ... 1 more field]

scala> df2.groupBy("age_range_id").count().show
+------------+-----+
|age_range_id|count|
+------------+-----+
|         8.0|    2|
|         7.0|    1|
|        11.0|    3|
|        14.0|    2|
|         3.0|    2|
|         2.0|    1|
|        17.0|    1|
|        10.0|    1|
|         5.0|    3|
|        15.0|    2|
|        16.0|    1|
|        12.0|    1|
+------------+-----+
```

---

Alternatively you can use Spark SQL API:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tab")

val query = """
with t as (select int(age/5) as age_id from tab)
select age_id, count(*) as count
from t
group by age_id
"""
spark.sql(query).show
```

Result:

```
scala> spark.sql(query).show
+------+-----+
|age_id|count|
+------+-----+
|    12|    1|
|    16|    1|
|     3|    2|
|     5|    3|
|    15|    2|
|    17|    1|
|     8|    2|
|     7|    1|
|    10|    1|
|    11|    3|
|    14|    2|
|     2|    1|
+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 8):

You can bucket the ages by this formula `range_start = age - (age % interval)`

Here is `interval` is `5`

Creating test dataframe for demo

```
val df = (100 to 400 by 7).map(id => (s"user$id", id % 60))
  .toDF("name", "age")

df.show(false)

+-------+---+
|name   |age|
+-------+---+
|user100|40 |
|user107|47 |
|user114|54 |
|user121|1  |
|user128|8  |
|user135|15 |
|user142|22 |
|user149|29 |
|user156|36 |
|user163|43 |
|user170|50 |
|user177|57 |
|user184|4  |
|user191|11 |
|user198|18 |
|user205|25 |
|user212|32 |
|user219|39 |
|user226|46 |
|user233|53 |
+-------+---+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Bucket the ages by `interval`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val interval = 5
df.withColumn("range", $"age" - ($"age" % interval))
  .withColumn("range", concat($"range", lit(" - "), $"range" + interval)) //optional one
  .groupBy($"range")
  .agg(collect_list($"name").as("names")) //change it to needed agg function or anything
  .show(false)

+--------+------------------------------------+
|range   |names                               |
+--------+------------------------------------+
|10 to 15|[user191, user254, user310, user373]|
|50 to 55|[user114, user170, user233, user352]|
|5 to 10 |[user128, user247, user366]         |
|55 to 60|[user177, user296, user359]         |
|45 to 50|[user107, user226, user289, user345]|
|35 to 40|[user156, user219, user275, user338]|
|25 to 30|[user149, user205, user268, user387]|
|30 to 35|[user212, user331, user394]         |
|0 to 5  |[user121, user184, user240, user303]|
|20 to 25|[user142, user261, user324, user380]|
|15 to 20|[user135, user198, user317]         |
|40 to 45|[user100, user163, user282]         |
+--------+------------------------------------+
```

We can even use UDF also with same formula but that might be slightly slow.