# Multiple pyspark "window()" calls shows error when doing a "groupBy()"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This question is a follow up of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48467533/865883). Spark is displaying an error when the following situation arises:

```
# Group results in 12 second windows of "foo", then by integer buckets of 2 for "bar"
fooWindow = window(col("foo"), "12 seconds"))

# A sub bucket that contains values in [0,2), [2,4), [4,6]...
barWindow = window(col("bar").cast("timestamp"), "2 seconds").cast("struct<start:bigint,end:bigint>")

results = df.groupBy(fooWindow, barWindow).count()
```

The error is:

> "Multiple time window expressions would result in a cartesian product
>   of rows, therefore they are currently not supported."

Is there some way to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution using an adaptation of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46988581/865883).

Note: This solution only works if there is at most one call to `window`, meaning multiple time windows are not allowed. Doing a quick search on the [spark github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/Analyzer.scala#L2729) shows there's a hard limit of `<= 1` windows.

By using `withColumn` to define the buckets for each row, we can then group by that new column directly:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td

start = dt.now()
second = td(seconds=1)
data = [(start, 0), (start+second, 1), (start+ (12*second), 2)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ('foo', 'bar'))

# Create a new column defining the window for each bar
df = df.withColumn("barWindow", F.col("bar") - (F.col("bar") % 2))

# Keep the time window as is
fooWindow = F.window(F.col("foo"), "12 seconds").start.alias("foo")

# Use the new column created
results = df.groupBy(fooWindow, F.col("barWindow")).count().show()

# +-------------------+---------+-----+
# |                foo|barWindow|count|
# +-------------------+---------+-----+
# |2019-01-24 14:12:48|        0|    2|
# |2019-01-24 14:13:00|        2|    1|
# +-------------------+---------+-----+
```